# Expressing a Recursive Sequence in a Non-Recursive Form

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursive-algorithms

I am working on a recursive sequence and wondering if it's possible to convert it into a non-recursive form. The sequence is defined as follows:

$$  a_n = a_{n-1} \times (n + 1) + n!  $$

with the initial condition $  a_1 = 3  $. The term $ n!  $ represents the factorial of $ n $, and $ a_{n-1} $ is the previous term in the sequence.

So far, I've considered breaking down the sequence into sums and products, but I'm still not sure how to approach the problem effectively. The interaction between the factorial term and the multiplication by the previous term adds complexity to the sequence.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to express this sequence in a non-recursive form?
2. What strategies or mathematical concepts might be helpful in approaching this problem, especially considering my thoughts on dividing it into sums and products?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Is $N$ a constant? Then there is nothing special about $N+1$ and $N!$.  Or is it supposed to be $n$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael It is supposed to be $n$. Sorry my mistake.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A000254](https://oeis.org/A000254).  Note that the indexing is slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

I consider the indexing of [OEIS sequence A000254](https://oeis.org/A000254) (the link provided above by @RobertIsrael), that is:
$$ a_{n+1} = a_n\times (n+1) + n! \quad \mbox{with} \quad a_0\in\mathbb{C}.$$
Expressing $a_{n+2}$ depending on $a_n$ and then $a_{n+3}$ depending on $n$ leads to conjecturing the formula
$$ a_n = n!\left( a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 k \right).$$
The proof is straightforward by induction: denoting by $b$ the sequence corresponding to the right-hand term, $b_0=a_0$ by definition and
\begin{align*}
 b_{n+1} &= (n+1)n! \left( a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 k + \frac 1 {n+1} \right) \\
&= (n+1)b_n + n!.
\end{align*}

With your indexing this corresponds to
$$ a_n = (n+1)!\left( a_{-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac 1 k\right).$$
Using that $a_{1}=3$, the above yields
$$ 3 = 2! \left( a_{-1} + \frac 3 2 \right),$$
that is, $a_{-1} = 0$ and
$$ a_n = (n+1)! \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac 1 k.$$

We recognize [Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) for the sum, and thus $a_n$ can be expressed as a [Stirling number of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind):
$$ a_n = \begin{bmatrix} n+2 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm seeking a formula without summation. Notably, for the $n$-th term of the series, subtracting $\frac{(n+1)! \cdot 3}{2!}$ and then dividing terms at multiples of 6 by $n^2$ yields integers. This pattern suggests a potential underlying relation. Could this imply a summation-free expression for the series?

Comment: I edited my post to answer your comment question.

Comment: Thank you for your continued guidance. I'm seeking an expression that utilizes powers, factorials, multiplications, divisions, and other elementary operations, without involving complex functions like the lower incomplete gamma function or summations.

Comment: This amounts to a more "simple" expression of harmonic numbers, what I've not heard of.